# How can I insert a string before the file suffix in a makefile?

Tags: makefile

I want to copy a file but insert a string before the suffix of the file

```
TARGET = executable.exe
VERSION = 1.2.3

myrule:
    cp $(TARGET) SOMEFUNCTION($(TARGET), $(VERSION))
```

So on windows this produces executable1.2.3.exe and on linux this would produce executable1.2.3 (with the target obviously not having the .exe as well)

Do I need to create two rules, one for windows which removes the extension and readds it and one for linux which just concats, or is there some better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to specify the `.exe` extension at all. Windows adds it automatically when linking the executable file.

---

If the executable is already created, this should do the trick :

```make
$(CP) $(TARGET) $(basename $(TARGET))$(VERSION)$(suffix $(TARGET))
```

If `$(TARGET)` has no period in it, then `$(suffix $(TARGET))` will be an empty string.

Comment: I probably should have been more specific, but look at the example: this done after compilation (i.e. gcc is nowhere involved here or in this makefile)